# Using "not only" without clarifying what else was done

Tags: grammar, only

Consider the sentence:

> I did not only go to the store.

It has the same meaning as

> Going to the store was not the only thing I did.

Is the first sentence grammatically correct, or do I need to add an independent clause to it?

Comment: The first sentence is nonsense.

Comment: I do not *only* disagree with the previous comment, but I also think the first sentence makes complete sense. It's less common to omit a second clause, but that doesn't mean it's wrong to do so. If *I did not go to the store* is fine (which it is), then *I did not only go to the store* is also fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I did not only go to the store.**

The sentence is grammatically correct, but it does beg a second clause or sentence(s).

As in:  [Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?id=pchLsVMR6ToC&lpg=PT170&ots=bs3zXMQo-n&dq=%22I%20did%20not%20only%20go%22&pg=PT170#v=onepage&q=%22I%20did%20not%20only%20go%22&f=true)

*Going Down Under Over*

> **I did not only go Down Under.**

The second sentence cited from Google Books:

> It is a great story to show how God took my family to Australia.

In context I would suspect the next sentence(s) would explain what else one did on the trip to the store.